# How to display Toast message with custom field value as its message

Tags: lightning, javascript, controller, popup, toast

I have a requirement to display message toast on detail page when any record is opened.
This message will be from a custom field (Alert_Text__c) on Account which is a text field.

Below is the code to display toast message

Lightning component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <div>
        <lightning:button label="Information"
                          variant="brand"
                          onclick="{!c.showInfo}"/>
        
    </div> 
</aura:component>
```

Javascript:

```
({
    showInfo : function(component, event, helper) {
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            title : 'Info',
            message: 'This is an information message.',
            duration:' 5000',
            key: 'info_alt',
            type: 'info',
            mode: 'dismissible'
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Now, is there any way to display value of Alert_Text__c as a message when this button is clicked instead of pre-defined message.
Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but you'll need to load that data first:

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Map" default="{}" />
    <aura:attribute name="disabled" type="Boolean" default="true" />
    <force:recordData targetFields="{!v.record}"
        recordId="{!v.recordId}"
        recordUpdated="{!c.recordLoaded}"
        fields="Alert_Text__c" />
    <div>
        <lightning:button label="Information"
                          variant="brand"
                          disabled="{!v.disabled}" 
                          onclick="{!c.showInfo}"/>
        
    </div> 
</aura:component>
```

Then, you can display the message as you'd expect:

```
({
    recordLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.disabled", false);
    },
    showInfo : function(component, event, helper) {
        var record = component.get("v.record");
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            title : 'Info',
            message: record.Alert_Text__c,
            duration:' 5000',
            key: 'info_alt',
            type: 'info',
            mode: 'dismissible'
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. Is there any way that I can enable/disable or highlight the button only when the Alert_Text__c field is changed. Please suggest

Comment: @SK_112 Sure, I've added in the necessary code to make that happen.

Comment: When I tried your given suggestion, I am getting the error as "The attribute "recordUpdated" was not found on the COMPONENT markup://lightning:button"

Comment: @SK_112 Sorry, that was a typo, should have been `=`.

Comment: I tried with '=' instead of ':' 
Then I encountered this error. It looks like recordUpdated is not supported by lightning button

Comment: @SK_112 Yes, you're right. I put it on the wrong element. This (hopefully) final edit should solve your request.

Comment: Now I'm not getting any error but the button is being enabled always, I mean it is not getting disabled. Could you please suggest any changes here?

Comment: @SK_112 It may be loading too fast for you to tell it's not ready, since the record is already in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the Alert_Text__c field in the component? You will have to fetch the value via a SOQL in a controller that is exposed to the component or use Lightning data service:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_load_record.htm

to fetch the field value. Pass this to the **message** attribute.